# Mount a local data directory into jupyterhub

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook, dockerfile

I build and run jupyterhub a docker image. https://hub.docker.com/r/joergklein/jupyterhub

Is it a good idea to mount  in the Dockerfile

```
# Create a mountpoint
VOLUME /data
```

or is it better to mount to

```
# Create a mountpoint
VOLUME /home/data
```

I have a local data dir on my computer. I will mount the data dir into the container /data or /home/data.

At first I download and install the image

`docker run -p 8000:8000 -d --name jupyterhub joergklein/jupyterhub jupyterhub`

Second I will mount the datasets dir. into the /data in the container. In the dataset dir are a lot of csv files.

`docker run -v /home/user/datasets:/data -t jupyterhub /bin/bash`

I want run the JupyterHub in a sub domain in a team.

1. We want share the data. How can all team member work in this directory?
2. How we can add new data in this directory?
3. Which is the right docker run commnd?

Comment: I don't completely understand your question. You define the volumes when you create the container, you can't create a container and afterwards attach a volume to it. Each time you do `docker run` you're creating a new container based from your image.

Answer (score 0):

That works fine for me.

```
docker run -p 8000:8000 -d --name jupyterhub --volume $(pwd)/datasets:/data joergklein/jupyterhub jupyterhub
```